# Predictive Margins After Mixed-Effect Tobit

Tags: regression, mixed-model, stata, tobit-regression, marginal-effect

I'm hoping to get advice on the difference between two predictive margins outputs after running a mixed-effect tobit regression (in Stata 16.0).

Here is a sample output (modified from my actual case), where the dependent variable (score) is censored from above and below. We also have an interaction term present in the model.

```
. metobit score ib2.sex##ib1.socioeconomic_status ||site:, ul(33) ll(0) nolog

Mixed-effects tobit regression                  Number of obs     =      2,517
                                                   Uncensored     =      1,908
Limits: lower = 0                                  Left-censored  =        605
        upper = 33                                 Right-censored =          4

Group variable:            site                 Number of groups  =         18
                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          1
                                                              avg =      139.8
                                                              max =        544

Integration method: mvaghermite                 Integration pts.  =          7

                                                Wald chi2(5)      =     157.08
Log likelihood = -6742.3941                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   score |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                   1.sex |  -1.086671   .8398094    -1.29   0.196    -2.732667    .5593255
                         |
    socioeconomic_status |
                      2  |   4.746687   .6094876     7.79   0.000     3.552114    5.941261
                      3  |   2.188796   .5561682     3.94   0.000     1.098726    3.278866
                         |
sex#socioeconomic_status |
                    1 2  |   1.175162   .9674324     1.21   0.224    -.7209706    3.071295
                    1 3  |   .1404838   .9092797     0.15   0.877    -1.641672    1.922639
                         |
                   _cons |   3.722792   1.754563     2.12   0.034     .2839111    7.161673
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
site                     |
               var(_cons)|   48.08904    17.2385                      23.81856    97.09051
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             var(e.score)|   39.85155   1.345925                        37.299    42.57878
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. tobit model: chibar2(01) = 1258.16        Prob >= chibar2 = 0.0000
```

I'm interested in predicting the scores, fixing certain values of interest (i.e., sex and socio-economic status), while leaving the other values at their observed value. This can be done using Stata's default "asobserved" function. In the predictive margins output below, I deliberately exclude the **predict(ystar(0,33))** extension -- which is used to censor the predictions. The predicted scores, without this extension however, match up with the regression output posted above. For example, the regression coefficient for sex (-1.087) can be back-calculated by subtracting the predicted scores between socioeconomic_status#sex (3.72 - 2.63), given the coefficient for sex in the regression is the difference at the base-level of "1" for socio-economic status:

```
. margins i.socioeconomic_status##i.sex

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      2,517
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Marginal linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |            Delta-method
                         |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    socioeconomic_status |
                      1  |   3.292355   1.726483     1.91   0.057    -.0914902      6.6762
                      2  |   8.504531    1.69834     5.01   0.000     5.175847    11.83322
                      3  |   5.536797   1.688287     3.28   0.001     2.227816    8.845778
                         |
                     sex |
                      1  |   5.706036   1.694424     3.37   0.001     2.385027    9.027045
                      2  |    6.37486   1.687879     3.78   0.000     3.066679    9.683041
                         |
socioeconomic_status#sex |
                    1 1  |   2.636121   1.804892     1.46   0.144    -.9014013    6.173644
                    1 2  |   3.722792   1.754563     2.12   0.034     .2839111    7.161673
                    2 1  |   8.557971   1.721823     4.97   0.000      5.18326    11.93268
                    2 2  |   8.469479   1.711487     4.95   0.000     5.115027    11.82393
                    3 1  |   4.965401    1.70449     2.91   0.004     1.624661    8.306141
                    3 2  |   5.911588   1.693488     3.49   0.000     2.592413    9.230762
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The second predicted margins output includes the **predict(ystar(0,33))** extension into the command:

```
. margins i.socioeconomic_status##i.sex, predict(ystar(0,33))

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      2,517
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : E(score*|0<score<33), predict(ystar(0,33))

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |            Delta-method
                         |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    socioeconomic_status |
                      1  |   5.619221   1.097938     5.12   0.000     3.467302     7.77114
                      2  |   9.421321   1.381066     6.82   0.000     6.714481    12.12816
                      3  |   7.142504   1.216324     5.87   0.000     4.758552    9.526455
                         |
                     sex |
                      1  |   7.325288   1.223074     5.99   0.000     4.928107     9.72247
                      2  |   7.791398   1.259778     6.18   0.000     5.322279    10.26052
                         |
socioeconomic_status#sex |
                    1 1  |   5.204548   1.100674     4.73   0.000     3.047266     7.36183
                    1 2  |   5.891215   1.145994     5.14   0.000     3.645108    8.137321
                    2 1  |   9.464794   1.402626     6.75   0.000     6.715697    12.21389
                    2 2  |   9.392806   1.390159     6.76   0.000     6.668143    12.11747
                    3 1  |   6.732649   1.193513     5.64   0.000     4.393406    9.071892
                    3 2  |   7.411337   1.242576     5.96   0.000     4.975931    9.846742
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The values in some cases are quite different.

I expected that when I added in the **predict(ystar, 0,33)** extension, my margins results would have actually resembled those seen in the *first* margins output, which matches up with the censored regression output posted. Why am I wrong?

Comment: `margins` has an undocumented generate option, which you can use to store individual level predictions with the sex & SEs adjusted values. I would suggest getting the uncensored predictions and making sure the output of the first margins matches that. Then censor them by hand to get a sense of what is happening with the second, and make sure that matches. It's not inconceivable that if there are lots of negative values in the 1#1 cell with y=2.636121 and only a few above 33, then when you censor the mean jumps up to 5.204548.